# Calculate SUM in MySQL for todays date #Parse error

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
    //Result;
    //select the sum in here;
    $sumQry = "SELECT SUM(amount) FROM login WHERE tdate = '<?php echo date("F d, Y" ,time()); ?>"  />' ";
}
?>
```

**ERROR** Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in ... on line 4

i want to calculate the sum of numbers ( i mean like 10+50+85+90) for today date and diplsay the sum in fount end. so used the above code. but i think some thing wrong with `<?php echo date("F d, Y" ,time()); ?>`

---

**UPDATE**
Ok. Thanks guys! Leave about date. but i am not able to display the sum for total also.

Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in **  on line 3

```
<?php
include "db.php";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
    //Result;
    //select the sum in here;
    $sumQry = "SELECT SUM(amount) FROM login";
}
?>
```

Comment: Just an FYI, using PHP tags within the query string will do you no good. You're already building the query string within PHP, so use concatenation with `.` to add the output of a function like `date()` to the string as you see in @pvnarula's answer.

Comment: Check now. Note while loop is not needed because a single result will be returned because of the group.

Comment: Also I used mysqli instead of mysql since mysql is deprecated. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you modify the MySQL table and use either DATE, DATETIME or TIMESTAMP.

They way you do it your field is CHAR or VARCHAR, that means indexing even if present will not work properly.

If you have the field as one of the above they can be indexed and performance of your query will be optimal even on a large number of records.

Thing is DATE, DATETIME and TIMESTAMP are stored numerically by MySQL. Also you will be able to sort by this field if you ever need to show more then a record and want to order by this field.

```
$sumQry = "SELECT SUM(`amount`) FROM `login` WHERE `tdate` = ". date("Y-m-d" ,time());
$sumQry = "SELECT SUM(`amount`) FROM `login` WHERE `tdate` = ". date("Y-m-d H:i:s" ,time());
$sumQry = "SELECT SUM(`amount`) FROM `login` WHERE `tdate` = ". time();
```

I also added the MySQL fields quote because even if it's not necessarily most of the time, it is a good thing to use. If you have a large JOINed query it will perform up to 5% better with them. They are also good if you by any chance use reserved words as field names.

Your code should look like this:

```
include "db.php";
$res = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT SUM(`amount`) FROM `login` WHERE `tdate` = '". date("Y-m-d" ,time() . "' GROUP BY `ammount`;");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
echo $row[1];
```

In db.php you should have something like:

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');
```

Comment: @tinu thanks :) i have updated my question, kindly please check it ones now

Answer (score 0):

If tdate is not an INT datatype in the db you need to encapsulate the value in quotes:

```
$sumQry = 'SELECT SUM(amount)
           FROM login 
           WHERE tdate = "'.date("F d, Y" ,time()).'"';
```

Comment: @ilwrence cherone thanks :) i have updated my question, kindly please check it ones now

Comment: @user2457175 you need todo the query first, freshen up on some php/sql tutorials